# what is the definition of one nCK in ddr?

Tags: memory

If ddr4 runs at 1600Mhz, then what is the value of nCk? is it 625ps? if so, then does nCk simply means speed of one of  clock cycle at which ddr4 runs?

Comment: What is nCK? What chip or design did this come from?